# Username filter does not abort old pending Ajax requests

Tags: bug, status-completed

We are all familiar with the three dots loader of StackOverflow. Recently I found a minor bug when performing a seach on users. The search is triggered every time you stop writing and an ajax request is made with the new query.

In the following photo there are 6 concurrent requests. In mi opinion those request should be canceled before sending a new one or no requests should be made when another is still in progress. All this affects the web server performance.

[image: requests]

Also a new loader is added every time one of this requests is made making a very curious effect.

[image: bug]

Comment: That's an... unusual profile pic you caught there.

Comment: I didn't see that x) sorry. I was searching for john doe and turns out that there are a lot of those in stack overflow

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/loading-indicator-is-reproducing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a symptom of a (slightly) bigger issue with the user search code: if the Ajax requests to load the filtered user list take more than 500ms to complete, the current implementation is happy to launch new requests even while there are earlier ones pending.  Besides being slightly wasteful of bandwidth and server resources, it could potentially cause incorrect output if the requests complete out of order.

Anyway, this would be trivial to fix.  In fact, let me post a [patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) (against the inline JS code used on the [users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users)):

```js
--- old.js  2015-07-17 16:06:03.294734128 +0300
+++ new.js  2015-07-17 16:07:12.446733344 +0300
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
     $(function () {
                 $("#userfilter").val("").focus().typeWatch({ highlight: true, wait: 500, captureLength: -1, callback: finished(false) });
+        var request = null;
         function finished(all) {

             var showingAll = all;
@@ -16,7 +17,8 @@

                     var spinner = $("#userfilter").addSpinnerAfter({ 'margin-left': "8px", 'margin-bottom': '-4px' }).next();

-                    $.ajax({
+                    if (request) request.abort();
+                    request = $.ajax({
                         url: url,
                         data: {
                             search: search,
```

That's two extra lines (`var request = null;` and `if (request) request.abort();`) and one change to an existing line (adding `request =` before `$.ajax({`).

This patch will cause any pending Ajax requests for filtered user lists to be aborted whenever a new request is launched.  As a side effect, it also gets rid of the extra spinners (since aborting the request triggers the `complete` callback, which removes the spinner).

*Ps.* I'll leave fixing the similar bug on the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) as an exercise.  (This one isn't so visually conspicuous, since there's no spinner.)  Or you could just borrow the code from [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), which includes a client-side fix for both versions of this bug as of v1.32. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Don't stop so frequently ;)

Comment: what's the point to allow people from posting bugs if you are never gonna fix them. The problem is not only visual. It adds more load to the server for no reason and this is the way normally people search. You ask me to stop and I will of course but don't expect your other users to do that. SO is a place where programmers gather, every programmer groan when they see that. I'm sure you people have the talent to fix that tiny problem.

Comment: This is about priorities. This is a small bug that has very little effect on the site and its users (also - happens rarely - I can't trigger it at all, since the response times from the server are very quick for me). I'd rather fix higher priority bugs - don't you?

Comment: @Oded: Does this at least have enough priority for someone to [apply a patch](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299529)?

Comment: I'll take a look on Monday, @Ilmari

Comment: @Oded: It's Monday now. Have you had a chance to take a look at this yet? :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - errr. With you in the next build (also on Tags page)